# Bootstrap 3: Break responsive into different row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm currently trying to implement following layouts in bootstrap 3.2, but I really don't have a clue how to do it.

Desktop layout (md):

```
--------------------------------------------
| text1                       |            |
-------------------------------    abc     |
|  text2        |    text3    |    def     |
|               |             |            |
--------------------------------------------
```

mobile layout (xs):

```
--------------------------------------------
| text1                                    |
-------------------------------------------|
|             text2           |            |
------------------------------|    abc     |
|             text3           |    def     |
|                             |            |
--------------------------------------------
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Basically I have to break into the second row with the two columns, I guess...

Comment: And what about at sm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two right menu and hide one of them.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/maxlipsky/mhfb97ed/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 bg-primary ">
                    text1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 bg-warning">text2</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 bg-success">text3</div>
                    </div>            
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 bg-danger hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    abc<br/>
                    def
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-danger hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            abc<br/>
            def
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. I hoped it would be possible without duplicate content, but this works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Also you can use other version of menu on mobile.